# tomahawk dataScroller don't show numbers pages

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

tomahawk dataScroller show only:

```
|<  <<  <       >   >>  >|
```

and not divides table on pages, shows all together

below part of jsp page:

```
<t:dataTable
    id="resultTable"
    value="#{customerSearchResults}"
    var="customerInfo" >
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Account #" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{customerInfo.accountNumber}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Customer Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{customerInfo.name}" />
    </h:column>
</t:dataTable>
<t:dataScroller 
    id="paginatorForResTable" 
    for="resultTable" 
    fastStep="10"
    paginatorMaxPages="9" 
    renderFacetsIfSinglePage="true"
    paginator="true"
    immediate="true"
    >
    <f:facet name="first">
        <h:outputText value="|&lt;" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="previous">
        <h:outputText value="&lt;" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="next">
        <h:outputText value="&gt;" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputText value="&gt;|" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="fastforward">
        <h:outputText value="&gt;&gt;" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="fastrewind">
        <h:outputText value="&lt;&lt;" />
    </f:facet>
</t:dataScroller>
```

Does anyone know where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a really dumb question.

Adding attribute  `rows` to `t:dataTable`  helps in my case:

```
<t:dataTable
    id="resultTable"
    rows="10"
    value="#{customerSearchResults}"
    var="customerInfo" >
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Account #" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{customerInfo.accountNumber}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Customer Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{customerInfo.name}" />
    </h:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set two important attribuites:

- `pageIndexVar` - "A parameter name, under which the actual page index is set in request scope similar to the var parameter."
- `pageCountVar` - "A parameter name, under which the actual page count is set in request scope similar to the var parameter"

These should point to a property of a bean of yours. For example `#{customerBean.pageIndex}`

Comment: How this two attributes can help in my case?

I saw few examples without this attributes that worked well.

Anyway thanks